# Javascript slice method not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple javascript function which converts string to date (in format 'dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm').

For extracting parts of that string, I've used `slice` method.
What is strange to me is that only day is returned as expected. All other variables are simply empty strings. 
What am I doing wrong?

```js
(
  function(){
  alert(GetDateFromStringDateTime("20.04.2017 18:15"));
    
    
  }
  
  
)();


  function GetDateFromStringDateTime(dateStr){
  
  var day = dateStr.slice(0,2);
  var month = dateStr.slice(3,2);
  var year = dateStr.slice(6,4);
  var hour = dateStr.slice(11,2);
  var minute = dateStr.slice(14,2);
  
  return new Date(year,month,day,hour,minute);
  
  
  
  
}
```

Picture from console window (month, year, hour and minute are empty strings):

[image]

Comment: second argument is the end index not the number of characters

Comment: Can you please post this as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) use a start and end parameter which are both zero-based index

```js
console.log(GetDateFromStringDateTime("20.04.2017 18:15"));

function GetDateFromStringDateTime(dateStr) {

  var day = dateStr.slice(0, 2);
  var month = dateStr.slice(3, 5);
  var year = dateStr.slice(6, 10);
  var hour = dateStr.slice(11, 13);
  var minute = dateStr.slice(14, 16);
  console.log(day);
  console.log(month);
  console.log(year);
  console.log(hour);
  console.log(minute);

  return new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.prototype.substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) instead of `slice`

Comment: yeah, a little mistake